# docker block my internet to other websites / can't access to other websites when using docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, Docker version 20.10.8.
Issue: when I am using docker (type `docker-compose up` in my terminal, I use docker file), I can search in google or firefox, but I can NOT open the webpages, I can NOT get access to some other websites like amazon, StackOverflow, instacart, etc. It shows "This site can’t be reached".

If I type `sudo cat /var/log/syslog`, I got this:

> Sep 15 11:02:59 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:02:59:922]
> info: [API-Q] (T07RRCX35) f5a63264-1663254179.919 client.counts is
> ENQUEUED Sep 15 11:03:01 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22,
> 11:03:01:920] info: [CHECK-FOR-OLD-IMS] (T7TUUDHHN) Within limit
> [external DMs]: 0 Sep 15 11:03:01 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:01:920] info: [CHECK-FOR-OLD-IMS] (T7TUUDHHN) Within
> limit [internal DMs]: 3 Sep 15 11:03:01 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:01:921] info: [API-Q] (T7TUUDHHN)
> f5a63264-1663254181.921 users.channelSections.list called with reason:
> conditional-fetch-manager Sep 15 11:03:01 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:01:921] info: [API-Q]
> (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254181.921 users.channelSections.list is
> ENQUEUED Sep 15 11:03:01 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22,
> 11:03:01:962] info: [API-Q] (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254181.921
> users.channelSections.list is ACTIVE Sep 15 11:03:03 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:03:920] info: [API-Q]
> (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254183.919 client.counts called with
> reason: client-counts-api/fetchClientCounts Sep 15 11:03:03 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:03:920] info: [API-Q]
> (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254183.919 client.counts is ENQUEUED Sep 15
> 11:03:09 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:09:920] info:
> [API-Q] (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254189.920 client.counts called with
> reason: client-counts-api/fetchClientCounts Sep 15 11:03:09 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:09:920] info: [API-Q]
> (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254189.920 client.counts is ENQUEUED Sep 15
> 11:03:10 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:10:575] info:
> [API-Q] (T03U4EJLT) f5a63264-1663254165.925 client.counts is ERROR:
> request did not complete Sep 15 11:03:13 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:13:555] info: [API-Q] (TKF75556W)
> f5a63264-1663254165.960 users.channelSections.list is ERROR: request
> did not complete Sep 15 11:03:13 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:13:555] info: [API-Q] (TKF75556W)
> f5a63264-1663254170.919 client.counts is ACTIVE Sep 15 11:03:13 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:13:651] info: [API-Q]
> (T07RRCX35) f5a63264-1663254171.921 users.channelSections.list is
> ERROR: request did not complete Sep 15 11:03:13 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:13:651] info: [API-Q]
> (T07RRCX35) f5a63264-1663254179.919 client.counts is ACTIVE Sep 15
> 11:03:14 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:14:920] info:
> [API-Q] (TKF75556W) f5a63264-1663254165.960 users.channelSections.list
> is retrying, attempt 2 Sep 15 11:03:14 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:14:920] info: [API-Q] (TKF75556W)
> f5a63264-1663254165.960 users.channelSections.list is ENQUEUED Sep 15
> 11:03:15 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:15:920] info:
> [API-Q] (T03U4EJLT) f5a63264-1663254165.925 client.counts is retrying,
> attempt 2 Sep 15 11:03:15 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22,
> 11:03:15:920] info: [API-Q] (T03U4EJLT) f5a63264-1663254165.925
> client.counts is ENQUEUED Sep 15 11:03:15 pop-os
> slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:15:920] info: [API-Q]
> (T03U4EJLT) f5a63264-1663254165.925 client.counts is ACTIVE Sep 15
> 11:03:15 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:15:920] info:
> [API-Q] (T07RRCX35) f5a63264-1663254171.921 users.channelSections.list
> is retrying, attempt 2 Sep 15 11:03:15 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]:
> [09/15/22, 11:03:15:920] info: [API-Q] (T07RRCX35)
> f5a63264-1663254171.921 users.channelSections.list is ENQUEUED Sep 15
> 11:03:16 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:16:719] info:
> [API-Q] (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254173.921
> users.channelSections.list is ERROR: request did not complete Sep 15
> 11:03:16 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:16:719] info:
> [API-Q] (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254183.919 client.counts is ACTIVE
> Sep 15 11:03:21 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:21:922]
> info: [API-Q] (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254173.921
> users.channelSections.list is retrying, attempt 2 Sep 15 11:03:21
> pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:21:922] info: [API-Q]
> (T0390MPHBCN) f5a63264-1663254173.921 users.channelSections.list is
> ENQUEUED Sep 15 11:03:22 pop-os kernel: [96800.697247] [UFW BLOCK]
> IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a4:56:cc:bd:dc:61:08:00
> SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=34348
> PROTO=2  Sep 15 11:03:25 pop-os kernel: [96803.769337] [UFW BLOCK]
> IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:a4:56:cc:bd:dc:61:08:00
> SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF
> PROTO=2  Sep 15 11:03:25 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22,
> 11:03:25:840] info: [API-Q] (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254181.921
> users.channelSections.list is ERROR: request did not complete Sep 15
> 11:03:25 pop-os slack.desktop[117910]: [09/15/22, 11:03:25:844] info:
> [API-Q] (T7TUUDHHN) f5a63264-1663254189.920 client.counts is ACTIVE

---

### **Before starting docker,**

`route -n` gives:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0

172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0

192.168.144.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-be62c9f6aadf

`docker network list` gives

NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE

be62c9f6aadf   0-course-fall-2022_default   bridge    local

6ee13c43c492   bridge                       bridge    local

6f15c9584a6f   host                         host      local

9c4377540201   none                         null      local

`ip addr`  gives
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:2f:74:20:cc:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:2f:74:20:cc:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 44:af:28:30:96:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.169/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
valid_lft 162382sec preferred_lft 162382sec
inet6 2601:84:8900:9770:1b6f:ce0:b930:88eb/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
inet6 2601:84:8900:9770:7d59:93a5:a2d2:63be/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
inet6 fe80::ed79:4b63:ef2b:7fe9/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:66:6f:0f:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

47: br-be62c9f6aadf: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:c2:99:82:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.144.1/20 brd 192.168.159.255 scope global br-be62c9f6aadf
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:c2ff:fe99:82c8/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

---

### **After starting docker,**

`route -n` gives:

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 veth2dfd7b5

0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 veth2dfd7b5

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0

172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0

192.168.144.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-be62c9f6aadf

`docker network inspect be62c9f6aadf` gives:
[
{
"Name": "somename",
"Id": "be62c9f6aadf496bcb1a771ab91c12abe3224a20ef1fdf7e43be18c49279ffe5",
"Created": "2022-09-15T10:04:25.791740449-04:00",
"Scope": "local",
"Driver": "bridge",
"EnableIPv6": false,
"IPAM": {
"Driver": "default",
"Options": null,
"Config": [
{
"Subnet": "192.168.144.0/20",
"Gateway": "192.168.144.1"
}
]
},
"Internal": false,
"Attachable": true,
"Ingress": false,
"ConfigFrom": {
"Network": ""
},
"ConfigOnly": false,
"Containers": {
"4d898f2de0dccd8ae33d98c4fefc79617839e900080c146a02796e8a168df4e6": {
"Name": "0-course-fall-2022_ggtree_1",
"EndpointID": "1e9ac1158d47479fecc2634167aefddcfc55d047f54176e03a4948b6245687f2",
"MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:90:02",
"IPv4Address": "192.168.144.2/20",
"IPv6Address": ""
}
},
"Options": {},
"Labels": {
"com.docker.compose.network": "default",
"com.docker.compose.project": "0-course-fall-2022",
"com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
}
}
]

`ip addr` gives:

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:2f:74:20:cc:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:2f:74:20:cc:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 44:af:28:30:96:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.169/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
valid_lft 161995sec preferred_lft 161995sec
inet6 2601:84:8900:9770:253f:ef6d:b518:d3d3/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
inet6 2601:84:8900:9770:7d59:93a5:a2d2:63be/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
inet6 fe80::2544:291c:7ab:f742/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:66:6f:0f:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

47: br-be62c9f6aadf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
link/ether 02:42:c2:99:82:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.144.1/20 brd 192.168.159.255 scope global br-be62c9f6aadf
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:c2ff:fe99:82c8/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

57: veth2dfd7b5@if56: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-be62c9f6aadf state UP group default
link/ether 0a:98:ae:0f:6e:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 169.254.173.91/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global veth2dfd7b5
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::898:aeff:fe0f:6ecf/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

`docker network list` gives:

NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE

be62c9f6aadf   somename                     bridge    local

6ee13c43c492   bridge                       bridge    local

6f15c9584a6f   host                         host      local

9c4377540201   none                         null      local

Also, if I switch wifi to my personal hotspot, there is no problem with using docker.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may wish to provide details about your VPN, or any unusual DNS or traffic-shaping setup you have. I think it's likely something is trying to route your traffic through an IP whose range that gets taken over by docker

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I added the docker network information, any other commands do you think I could try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.